# Supervisord configured Environment variable in Java process

Tags: java, environment-variables, supervisord

My java process takes a env variable "config". It works when I shoot the process from command line with "java -Dconfig=... ..."

Now I have configured Supervisord and added the programs. I also have added
the below entry under supervisor tag in conf file

```
environment=KEY="value",config="my path"
```

I think this value should be propagated to all child processes, hence my child java process should be able to access it with System.getProperty(). But it is not getting any env variable with name "config".

Any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `environment` configuration parameter of Supervisord is for operating system (Linux) environment variables. Parameters passed using `-D`, on the other hand, are JVM options. The correct way is to pass JVM options in `command`.

```
command=java -Dconfig=...
```

Don't forget quotes if a command argument contains spaces. See http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that :)